# Network Driver seems to be loaded, but not in use?

Tags: networking, drivers, intel

I have a Intel x550 network card. I have installed the ixgbe driver. After installing the driver I run `/sbin/modinfo ixgbe | grep version` and get the result `5.3.6`. How ever running `ethtool -i` shows :

```
driver: ixgbe
version: 4.2.1-k
firmware version: 0x80000492
```

`sudo lshw -class network` shows

```
description: Ethernet Interface
product: Ethernet Controller 10G X550T
vendor: Intel Corporation
logical name: enp1s0f0
driver=ixgbe
driverversion=4.2.1-k
firmware=0x80000492
```

`dmesg | grep ixgbe` shows

```
Intel 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 4.2.1-k
enp1s-f-: renamed from eth0
```

Is it using the correct version 5.3.6 for the ixgbe driver? Do I need to force it to use the correct version other than running modprobe? I am stumped as to why it is showing driver version of 4.2.1-k. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

After the box reboots the `sudo lshw -class network | grep driver` shows it reset to 4.2.1-k. If I run

```
modprobe -r ixgbe 
modprobe ixgbe
```

It will show 5.3.6 for the lshw command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be initramfs. After successfully installing the driver issue the command:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

If an updated driver comes out, simply install and run the `update-initramfs -u` again.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you followed the instructions in the README in the package you downloaded. The 'make install' step builds and installs the driver for the currently running kernel version only. If, as an example, you build and install the driver while running kernel version 4.15.0-29, the driver is built and installed *only* for that kernel version.

If, a few days later, Update Manager offers and you install a newer kernel version, for example 4.15.0-30, then you must rebuild the driver for the newer kernel version:

```
cd ixgbe-5.3.6/src
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Next, unload the old driver version:

```
sudo modprobe -r ixgbe
```

And load the newer veersion that you just installed:

```
sudo modprobe ixgbe
```

Confirm the version:

```
modinfo ixgbe | grep version
```

You should see:

```
version:        5.3.6
```

Please retain these instructions as the process must be repeated every time Update Manager offers and you install a later kernel version.

Comment: The Kernel does not get updated on these boxes, but from what you wrote and the other sources I found online. It is using the correct driver. Removing the old driver does not change anything in the output.

Comment: I will update the post with the latest finds.